# Scrape facebook profile image link python3 selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, selenium

Question is hot to get facebook profile image link using python3, selenium

When inspecting profile photo element it gives:

```
<image style="height: 168px; width: 168px;" x="0" y="0" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" width="100%" xlink:href="https://scontent.fskp2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p160x160/66377281_10219519738489211_3470999363818356736_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&amp;_nc_ohc=wwARRHDG764AX8QTDeA&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.fskp2-1.fna&amp;_nc_tp=6&amp;oh=af9af2ffed61664c18229d3474cea541&amp;oe=5ECC34A6"></image>
```

However, $x('//image') gives 0 results. I'm already logged on facebook.
Any hint?

Comment: Do you have proper authentication to facebook?

Comment: yes, already logged in, scraped various things, but so far, I can't get photo url. I'm thinking now on idea of screenshot by coordinates.

Comment: You should login with your request,plus you need facebook api authentication to do this

Comment: you can't access href from image, you can get a screenshot of the image element.

Comment: Question would first of all much less be how, and actually more _why_. Why would you need to do this? Considering that it is explicitly against Facebook’s ToS, no less.

Comment: regardless of facebook aproval, that idea with screenshot and later cutting desired image sounds as nice direction. ToS :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how I solved this problem.

Idea of whole screen screenshot by browser (selenium) and then cutting photo to exact coordinates.

```
# selenium imports
from PIL import Image
...
driver.save_screenshot("shot.png")
x = 100
y = 80
w = 200
h = 220
width = x + w
height = y + h

im = Image.open('shot.png')
im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))
im.save('image.png')
```

Comment: Did it work for you